# Perform animation while view is being dragged

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a view which contains 2 image view that is using the ondraglistener to move them around the screen and that all works fine. I am now trying to animate one of the image views but I'm not sure if this effect is possible.

The animation works correctly but I can't get it to stick with the container view while it is being dragged around and still animate at the same time. It looks like once you start the dragging the view just freezes until the drag is finished. Any pointers on how to accomplish this or if it is even possible? Thanks for advice.

EDIT: It looks like I will have to override the DragShadowBuilder so I guess the next question is whether you can send in an animatable view to the DragShadowBuilder...

EDIT: I guess you can't do it with DragShadowBuilder at all so attempting to do it by overriding onTouch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a solution here is to override onTouch and kick off the animation when the click is first 'touched down' and then on touch move just update the margins (or use an x/y translation) based of the motion event's getX and getY and then when 'touch up' just stop the animation. Also the on touch has to be on a wrapper view rather than on the view where you are resetting the layout parameters. I can post the code if anyone is looking for a more concrete explanation.

Comment: Can u post the code? I am looking for animate  View.DragShadowBuilder .